# OpenCV - undefined symbol: hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I have a working anaconda environment on my ubuntu 17.10 machine and installed opencv3 using `conda install -c menpo opencv3`

When I try to import cv2 the following error shows up

> import cv2
>
> ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`, this one also will install opencv version 3.

For your error, you can fix it by install pango using `conda install -c conda-forge pango`

Comment: Thanks - fixed the problem for me.

Comment: conda install -c asmeurer pango - this worked for me - https://www.cnblogs.com/ranjiewen/p/9737346.html